# How to use custom marker symbols in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, symbology

I am new to CartoDB and haven't found a suitable answer to my search. I have a point layer uploaded to CartoDB and want to change the symbology to my own custom symbol - is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not very hard. If you open the [visualization wizard](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#wizards) you'll see `img` next to `marker-fill`. This allows you to customize the image you use for markers... (see the image below) There are pre-loaded ones you can use, or you can upload them from your computer or import them from the internet. SVG images work best because you can [style them further with CartoCSS](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/advanced-map-design/), but PNGs work as well but don't allow for styling.

[image: marker image options]